# Autoclick an element based on the color code [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I wanted to auto-click a button in a table. But that table is not shown in the "view-source". I am not sure what this is called. The table seems to be generated via javascript based on the filters selected by the user.

When I clicked on inspect-element, I saw the button id but it seems like it is random/different every time based on something that I can't put my finger on. So I was wondering if I can do something like

Search the color code in the webpage -> And auto-click it if it matches

Does that make sense?

Comment: If you were able to locate the button, you don't need its `id` as long as you know its location, relative to some other element that you can locate, you can navigate to it.

Comment: Could you show us some of the relevant code - in particular what is 'the color code'? Is it the color of the text, of the background, of some other element....

Comment: @AHaworth I am starting over. I want to select "background-color" of a class. Problem is the class name keeps on changing. So I want to write something that will select the class (class is for an 'anchor' tag) based on the color code (hex code) that I provide.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of the table which you see when you inspect the anchor element you are interested in.